# Truncate table in Play Framework/JPA/hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

In mysql, `DELETE FROM table` is much more expensive than `TRUNCATE TABLE table`

I believe that JPA's `Entity.deleteAll()` runs delete. What's the correct way to truncate instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TRUNCATE TABLE table` is not standard-SQL, so not generally supported. To do it, execute the query directly:

`em().createNativeQuery("truncate table MyTable").executeUpdate();`

While in a Play Model class (where you have access to the `EntityManager` with `em()`.